# php Length Required error when trying to send request using curl soap

Tags: php, curl, soap, libcurl

I need to form a request under this format:

```
    POST /CJW/cjws.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.somesite.abc.edu.sg
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetAll"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAll xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ErrorMsg>string</ErrorMsg>
    </GetAll>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So here is what I tried:

```
<?php
$username = '';
$password = '';
$credentials = $username.":".$password; 
//$url = "http://tempuri.org/GetAll";
$url = "http://www.somesite.abc.edu.sg/GetAll";

$soap_request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAll xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ErrorMsg>string</ErrorMsg>
    </GetAll>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$header = array(
"POST /CJW/cjws.asmx HTTP/1.1 \n",
"Host: www.somesite.abc.edu.sg \n",
"Content-type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\" \n",
"Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request)." \n",
"SOAPAction: ".$url." \n");


$curl = curl_init(); 


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap_request );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// perform the request

$xml_result = curl_exec($curl);
// check for errors
if ($xml_result === false) {
$error_occurred = true;
}
else {

    echo $xml_result;
}
?>
```

But I cannot get the response correctly, actually, I do not see the response except this error:

```
Length Required
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.
```

I tried many way including remove the length part, change it with some fix number, etc. but it changes nothing.
So what I am doing wrong here ? How is the right way ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

(You can remove Host: and Content-Length: from the headers you synthesize because curl will add them both itself if you don't set them.)

You should inspect your outgoing request in detail and verify that it looks exactly the way you want it to. Using CURLOPT_VERBOSE is usually enough but you need to be able to get that output somewhere for inspection.

I believe your custom headers all have a trailing space and a newline that you should remove. They will severely screw up the outgoing request. Oh, and the *POST* part must be removed from your custom headers (it is not a header, it is the "request-line").

Comment: I removed space and newline redundancy, remove host: and content-length; shorten the $soap_request into one line. It doesn't show the error but it load the whole website, not give the result. I use fiddler and it show "rare exceptions, server Must included a Date response header". I dont know what is that. And when I look at "RAW" in the debug window, the <soap:... content is not completed.

Comment: Well, unfortunately that's another problem which basically means your question here is actually solved. Date: is a response header that your frame-work seems to insist should be returned by the server.

Comment: No, actually it is not, in the web browser I still got the same error "HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length."

Comment: Then I guess the HTTP request still is munged somehow. Can you show us what it looks like when sent off?

Comment: In the raw I saw this:"POST http://www.somesite.abc.edu.sg/CJS/cjws.asmx?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Og==
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)
Host: www.simtech.a-star.edu.sg
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8""

Comment: I updated my response to also mention that you need to remove the POST part from your custom headers.

Comment: I removed the first line in the header ( with POST ) but same error! Is there anything else I can change ?